# Put a table* at the exact location and span across two columns

Tags: tables, positioning, longtable, multicolumn

I am using IEEE format which splits a page into two columns. I want to put a table at the exact location while it is too long so it has to span across two columns.

The layout should be like this:

```
\newpage % appendix starts from a new page
Section 1
table 1
table 2
...
Section 2
table 3
table 4
...
```

I tried `table*` but it cannot specify a exact location and the result would be like:

```
\newpage % appendix starts from a new page
Section 1
Section 2
table 1
table 2
table 3
table 4
...
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! Tables over two columns (i.e.  `table*`) can be only on the top of the next page where are inserted of in text. With use of `stfloats` packages can be at bottom of the page, if there is enough place. More precise is not possible to insert them.

Comment: In a two-column document, placing a full-width float anywhere else than at the very top or bottom of a page is a recipe for a typographic disaster. Don't even think about it.

Comment: To add to what @Mico says, that kind of position of a float has a very annoying effect: you do not *know* where you are supposed to continue reading... Anyway, this kind of insert is not supported by LaTeX.